# trying to import cucumber

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, cucumber

Hello I am following a course about selenium and cucumber, I am trying to import the dependencies of cucumber for the creation of a runner class but intellij does not recognize the dependencies.

this is my `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group = 'org.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java
    implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '4.11.0'
    implementation group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-java', version: '7.13.0'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:7.13.0'

}


test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

and this is the code i'm trying to

```java
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources/features",
        glue = "steps"
)
public class Runner {
}
```

the IDE only gives me the option to search for jar on web but when i click it, it does nothing. [see thi screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JPiN.png)

How do I import the dependencies correctly?

Comment: That course may be a bit old. Try starting with https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton for a working project.